# Timeout function in angularjs using PHP Laravel 4 framework to update inserted data

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-4

Actually I am trying to update the page automatic when the new data is inserted. means the displaying of new enered data on the view page. Can some one help ?
When I am inserting the data, I have to reload the page in order to view the new inserted data which is bulky and laborious. I want to rid of this work.

> VIEW

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="upd_cnt" class="container">
        <table border=1>
            <td>
                <h2>Rectangle dimension</h2><br/>
                    <table border=1>
                        <tr><td>Length:</td><td><input type="text" ng-model="lngth"><br/></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Breadth:</td><td><input type="text" ng-model="brdth"><br/></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input ng-click="store.reload();insertFunc(lngth,brdth)" type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
                    </table>

                    <svg width="400" height="200" version="1.1">
                        <rect fill="red" x="20" y="20" width="{{brdtha}}" height="{{lngtha}}" />
                        <rect fill="blue" x="50" y="50" width="200" height="75" />
                    </svg>
            </td>

            <td>
                <table border=1>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Length</th>
                        <th>Breadth</th>
                        <th>Draw Rectangle</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in select_rectangle">
                        <td>{{x.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.length}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.breadth}}</td>
                        <td><input ng-click='show = true' type="submit" value="Draw" ng-model="myVar"></td>
                        <td><svg width="400" height="200" version="1.1">
                        <rect fill="red" x="20" y="20" width="{{x.breadth}}" height="{{x.length}}" ng-init='show = false' ng-show='show'/></td>
                </svg>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>   

        </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    //$scope.insertFunc = function(lngth, brdth) {
    //$http.get("http://localhost/crud/public/insert_rectangle_dimension_page/"+lngth+"/"+brdth)
    $scope.insertFunc = $timeout(function(lngth,brdth) {
        $scope.lngtha = lngth;
        $scope.brdtha = brdth;

        $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'http://localhost/crud/public/insert_rectangle_dimension_page',
          data    : {lngth:$scope.lngth, brdth:$scope.brdth}
         })
        .then(function successCallback(response)
        {
            console.log('successCallback');
            console.log(response);
        },

        function errorCallback(response)
        {
            console.log('errorCallback');
            console.log(response);
        });

        }

        $http({method:'GET', url:'http://localhost/crud/public/rectangle_json_page'}).success(function(response){
        $scope.select_rectangle = response;
});
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Session;
use Redirect;

class NewController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
 public function rectangle_function(Request $request)
    {
      $select_rectangle = DB::select('select * from rectangle');
      return view('rectangle');
    }

    public function rectangle_json_function(Request $request)
    {
      $select_rectangle = DB::select('select * from rectangle order by id desc');
      return response($select_rectangle);
    }

    public function insert_rectangle_dimension_function(Request $request)
    {
      echo $rec_height = $request->lngth;
      echo $rec_width = $request->brdth;
      $rect = DB::table('rectangle')->insert(['length' => $rec_height, 'breadth' => $rec_width]);
    }
}
```

> ROUTE

```
    <?php

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
    | It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
    | and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
    |
    */

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::auth();
Route::post('/insert_rectangle_dimension_page', 'NewController@insert_rectangle_dimension_function');

Route::get('/rectangle', 'NewController@rectangle_function');

Route::get('/rectangle_json_page', 'NewController@rectangle_json_function');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call a function that gets your data again, after an insert. Apoloies for any errors in the code, I'm not used to injecting scope in angular controllers.
For example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {



  //$scope.insertFunc = function(lngth, brdth) {
    //$http.get("http://localhost/crud/public/insert_rectangle_dimension_page/"+lngth+"/"+brdth)
    $scope.insertFunc = $timeout(function(lngth,brdth) {
        $scope.lngtha = lngth;
        $scope.brdtha = brdth;
    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'http://localhost/crud/public/insert_rectangle_dimension_page',
      data    : {lngth:$scope.lngth, brdth:$scope.brdth}
     })
    .then(function successCallback(response)
    {
        console.log('successCallback');
        console.log(response);
        //Function call to re-load data
        $scope.loadData();
    },

    function errorCallback(response)
    {
        console.log('errorCallback');
        console.log(response);
    });

    }

      $scope.loadData = function(){
        $http({method:'GET', url:'http://localhost/crud/public/rectangle_json_page'}).success(function(response){
        $scope.select_rectangle = response;
});
      }//end scope.loadData

    });
```